# What is the orbiting technique involved for this scene [youtube]?

Tags: camera

As in title, what is the technique involved for this scene:

Scene starting from 0.43 to 0.48 secs, orbiting camera view with subjects at standstill.

My best guess is they had many cameras all taking a still shot all at once. Post processing stitch the still frames together. But the scene lasted for 5 seconds. In a 30 FPS video, we will need 150 still shots or 150 cameras!! How did they hide the cameras so well in the dark background? Not practical at all?

Hope someone can shed some light? Thank you all.

Comment: I believe this works by using only a small number of cameras, together with some really clever software which reconstructs a 3D model using stereoscopy and infers textures from the shots. It can then be re-rendered at any angle as slow as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dr Mayhem actually there might be 150 cameras! This video at 2:32 happen to show the behind the scenes. I think maybe many producers these days still prefer to use a method as direct as possible than rely on post processing manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you partially answered your own question - the dark background actually makes it easier to hide cameras. In saying that, these days a lot of the heavy work is done by interpolation software (as @romkyns mentioned), so I wouldn't think 150 cameras would be required here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation of how they achieved this effect in The Matrix: http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/question295.htm

Comment: I think this effect is different from The Matrix because it is simpler in Matrix's case. I do not even need to read up to guess it correctly. Mostly because it involves a subject (bullet, dodging man) in the foreground and then the background rotates around the subject. In this case however, the falling petals "interacts" with the foreground (girls) so I thought this is much complicated.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see the petals moving during the orbit effect.

Comment: I see the foreground petals scrolling side to side. Looks like they were added later.